# Remove Row If Not Unique By Keeping Another Column Value As Reference

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set for which I want to check all rows which has same column `U` value and the remove rows after which column `A`. It will be better if the row order doesn't change.

I tried using `duplicated()` but it didn't work out. Is there a better way to do this? Please suggest.

**Input Data**

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text ="U  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
A   C   1   2   31.9    32.1    1   32  32  32
                   A    D   1   3   31.9    32.1    1   32  32  32
                   B    C   1   4   31.9    32.1    1   32  32  32
                   B    D   1   5   31.9    32.1    1   32  32  32
                   ")
```

**Expected Output**

```
U   A   B   C      D       E    F   G   H   I
A   C   1   2   31.9    32.1    1   32  32  32
B   C   1   4   31.9    32.1    1   32  32  32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`duplicated` indeed works!

```
> data[!duplicated(data$U), ]
  U A B C    D    E F  G  H  I
1 A C 1 2 31.9 32.1 1 32 32 32
3 B C 1 4 31.9 32.1 1 32 32 32
```

Alternatively

```
> data[duplicated(data$U, fromLast = TRUE), ]
  U A B C    D    E F  G  H  I
1 A C 1 2 31.9 32.1 1 32 32 32
3 B C 1 4 31.9 32.1 1 32 32 32
```

Comment: .@JilberUrbina - Thank you. I gave a reproducible example which doesn't cover all aspect of my real data. What is the row `2` in the original input data has column `A` value as `C1` with column `U` value remaining as it's. I don't think this logic will remove the row `2`?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unique` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(data), by = "U")
#   U A B C    D    E F  G  H  I
#1: A C 1 2 31.9 32.1 1 32 32 32
#2: B C 1 4 31.9 32.1 1 32 32 32
```